# Can using OR in LEFT JOIN table1 ON condition1 OR condition2 cause unwanted issues?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am building a query joining multiple tables, and one table `prodRecipe` will have data for some rows, but not all, however `tmp_inv1` will have count information for everything. Problem is, the `tmp_inv1.count` is dependent on whether an item is in the `prodRecipe` table or not.

i.e. if `prodRecipe.product` is present, then `tmp_inv1.count` is based on that, otherwise it is based on `product.prodID`.

Using OR in the JOIN seems to work and populates according to whichever gives a valid result, but I'm wondering if this can cause unwanted or disastrous results that I am just not seeing yet?

--I tried using OR on a whim because I haven't been able to find a better solution. But the most important thing is that it is friendly with PHP, so I can't use multiple or nested select queries.--

```
SELECT invTrack AS track, varID, varSKU, revelSku, revelInvID, p.prodID AS prodID, pr.ingredient AS ing, pr.main_product AS mainProduct, pr.product AS product, i.invID AS invC, i.count,  pr.qty AS Xply
FROM shopifyProd sp
LEFT JOIN product p ON sp.revelSku = p.sku AND p.location = 1
LEFT JOIN prodRecipe pr ON p.prodID = pr.main_product
LEFT JOIN tmp_inv1 i ON pr.product = i.prodID OR p.prodID = i.prodID
WHERE 1
```

Comment: It shouldn't, but `on i.prodID in (pr.product, p.prodID)` is perhaps a little clearer in your intent.

Comment: Just trying to understand what exactly is happening, so,  `IN (pr.product, p.prodID)`  is essentially "look in these locations for a match"? And, if so, would that work with more variables? Also, although it's not the case, if there was a match in both variables, would it just list the first match?

Comment: You can try posting your question on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) too.

Comment: @mikey Thanks man! I'm not sure how that exchange has never come up in my google searching, and I have done a TON of google searching in my journey of learning MySQL.

Comment: @ZachDecamp using the OR/IN condition would join for all matches, not just the first; so you could have multiple result rows for the same `sp-p-pr` combination if `i` has a `p` and `pr` match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid multiple matches you'll need to join twice (once on each criteria) and choose the prioritized match.

```
SELECT invTrack AS track, varID, varSKU, revelSku, revelInvID, p.prodID AS prodID, pr.ingredient AS ing, pr.main_product AS mainProduct, pr.product AS product
, CASE WHEN p_i.prodID IS NOT NULL THEN p_i.invID ELSE pr_i.invID END AS invC
, CASE WHEN p_i.prodID IS NOT NULL THEN p_i.count ELSE pr_i.count END AS `count`
, pr.qty AS Xply
FROM shopifyProd sp
LEFT JOIN product p ON sp.revelSku = p.sku AND p.location = 1
LEFT JOIN prodRecipe pr ON p.prodID = pr.main_product
LEFT JOIN tmp_inv1 p_i ON p.product = p_i.prodID
LEFT JOIN tmp_inv1 pr_i ON pr.product = pr_i.prodID
WHERE 1
```